# Change the value of a property

Tags: javascript

i'm doing a exercise where there is that to change the value of the properties like energy and experience

```
let athlete = {
    energy:100,
    experience: 10,
  
    hoursTrained: function(hours) {
        this.energy - hours
        this.experience + hours
    }
}
```

the problem is that the property values ​​don't change, I don't know why it doesn't change if I'm referencing the properties

executing the code:

```
console.log('==Before of to start the training==')
console.log(`Energy of the athlete: ${athlete.energy}`)
console.log(`Experience of the athlete: ${athlete.experience}`)
console.log('==Athlete after of the training==') 
athlete.hoursTrained(5)
console.log(`Energy of the athlete ${athlete.energy}`)
console.log(`Experience of the athlete ${athlete.experience}`)
```

This is the result:

> ==Before of to start the training== 
> Energy of the athlete: 100 
> Experience of the athlete: 10 
> ==Athlete after of the training== 
> Energy of the athlete 100 
> Experience of the athlete 10

Comment: Use `-=`, not simply `-`.

Comment: Learn [variable assignment](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-assignment-operators/)

Comment: You are not updating the values of `energy` and `experience`. You have to update them as well `this.energy -= hours;` and `this.experience += hours;`

Comment: thanks, i already resolved the problem, the true i dont understand why to use -=, but, i will investigate

Answer (score 1):

Once check this code, the energy and experience has to be changed for the change in hours. So,

```
this.energy -=hours

this.experience +=hours
```

```js
let athlete = {
energy:100,
experience: 10,
  
hoursTrained: function(hours) {
    this.energy -= hours
    this.experience += hours
}
}
console.log("==Before of to start the training==");
console.log(`Energy of the athlete: ${athlete.energy}`);
console.log(`Experience of the athlete:${athlete.experience}`);
console.log("Athlete after of the training");
athlete.hoursTrained(5);
console.log(`Energy of the athlete ${athlete.energy}`);
console.log(`Experience of the athlete ${athlete.experience}`);
```

Comment: If you are going to answer a question, Try to make the code runnable. It helps OP and other user to understand better.